# Proof that $E(\hat{\beta^{'}}\hat{\beta})=\beta^{'}\beta+\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{\lambda_i}$

Tags: statistics, economics

I am having some difficulty proving the result above. I am considering $\hat{\beta}$ as the ols estimator of $\beta$ $(Y=X\beta +\epsilon)$ with $Var(\epsilon \mid X)=\sigma^2I$ and $\lambda_{i}$ a eigenvalue of matrix $(X'X)$.

So far, my development: $$E[\hat{\beta^{'}}\hat{\beta}]=E[[\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon]^{'}[\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon]]=E[\beta^{'}\beta+\beta^{'}(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon+\epsilon^{'}X(X'X)^{-1}\beta+\epsilon^{'}X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon]$$

And now I am stuck in this part.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Assuming $E[\varepsilon\mid X]=0$ and that $X$ has full column rank, I think you have $E(\hat\beta)=\beta$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\hat\beta)=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$. Then based on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48066/119261) standard result, $$E(\hat\beta'\hat\beta)=\beta'\beta+\sigma^2\operatorname{tr}((X'X)^{-1})$$

Comment: So, I basically need to use the same result considering $A$ equal to the identity matrix in this case?

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: Thank you very much!